# Django full calendar

Tags: javascript, python, django, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm trying to show the data from model in fullcalendar, here is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                events: [
                    {% for i in eventlist %}
                        {
                            title: "{{i.visit_patient_pesel}}",
                            start: "{{i.visit_start}}",
                            end: "{{i.visit_end}}",
                        },
                    {% endfor %}
                ]
 });
 });
```

The problem is that I've got several errors.
In this line `{% for i in eventlist %}` error is:

> identifier or string literal or numeric literal expected

(error is highlighted just where % is) and after "for" I've got

> ": or , expected".

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this code being interpreted server-side as part of the page/view?  Or did you put it in a separate `.js` file and it's being sent as-is to the client?  Where specifically is the error being reported?

Comment: I've put it in separate js file

Comment: It sounds like you need to put it in a page/view where you'd normally put Django code.  I don't know much about that framework specifically, but I do know that the browser won't know what to do with server-side code.  Try putting it in your HTML within a `<script>` element, treating it as part of any other page/view with server-side code.

Comment: yes, you are right. Is there any way to have the js code in separate file?

Comment: That I don't know, it would be specific to the Django framework.  I'm not sure I know enough about that framework to add a compelling answer below, but I can if you like.  Though you're certainly encouraged to as well for future visitors, explaining how the problem can be solved by moving it to the page/view and showing your Django structure accordingly.  It sounds like that next follow-up might be its own separate Stack Overflow question.

Comment: "Is there any way to have the js code in separate file"...not unless the JS file is processed and executed by Django/python on the server-side (so that the output of the python code can be turned into a data string) before being sent to the browser. And I doubt it will do that. But there is a better way to put your events into fullCalendar anyway - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed